# How to instantiate Map within a class?

Tags: c++

I'm making an encoding class. its currently failing to build. I'm instantiating a map from within a function and am getting the error message "Delete called on 'Map::Comparator' that is abstract but has non-virtual destructor". Any ideas how to get this to build?

Here's the header file;

```
#ifndef _encoding_
#define _encoding_

#include "bstream.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "map.h"
#include "HuffmanTypes.h"
#include "pqueue.h"


class Encoding {

public:
    Encoding();
    ~Encoding();

    void compress(ibstream& infile, obstream& outfile);
    void decompress(ibstream& infile, obstream& outfile);
    //Map<ext_char, std::string> *referenceTable;
    std::string compresskey;
private:


    string filename;
    Map<ext_char, int> getFrequency(ibstream& infile);
    void createHuffman();
    //Map<ext_char, int> *frequencyTable;

    HuffmanPQueue huffqueue;
    //void buildTree();
    //void createReferenceTable();
    //Node getNode(Node root);
    //void tracePaths(Node root, string path, int weight);


};

#endif
```

Here's the cpp file:

```
/**
 * File: encoding.cpp
 * ------------------
 * Place your Encoding class implementation here.
 */

#include "encoding.h"

#include "string.h"
#include "map.h"
#include "strlib.h"
#include "HuffmanTypes.h"
#include "pqueue.h"

using namespace std;

Encoding::Encoding() {

}

Encoding::~Encoding() {

}

void Encoding::compress(ibstream& infile, obstream& outfile) {

    Map<ext_char, int> frequencyTable;

    frequencyTable = getFrequency(infile);

    compresskey = "";


    foreach(ext_char key in frequencyTable) {

        int freq = frequencyTable.get(key);

        Node* newnode = new Node;
        newnode->character = key;
        newnode->weight = freq;
        newnode->zero = NULL;
        newnode->one = NULL;

        huffqueue.enqueue(newnode);
        string keystring = integerToString(key);
        string valstring = integerToString(freq);
        compresskey = compresskey + "Key = " + keystring + " " + "Freq = " + valstring + " ";

    }
    //buildTree();
    //createReferenceTable();

}

void Encoding::decompress(ibstream& infile, obstream& outfile) {

}

Map<ext_char, int> Encoding::getFrequency(ibstream& infile) {

    Map<ext_char, int> frequencyTable;

    int ch;

    while((ch = infile.get()) != EOF){
        if(frequencyTable.containsKey(ch)){
            int count;
            count = frequencyTable.get(ch);
            frequencyTable[ch] = ++count;
        }

        else {
            frequencyTable.put(ch, 1);
        }
    }
    frequencyTable.put(PSEUDO_EOF, 1);

    return frequencyTable;
}
```

Comment: A set, with an associated value for each key

Comment: The problem appears to be in Map and not in the code you've shown us. Map has a member Comparator. Comparator appears to be an abstract base class that does not have a virtual destructor. Can you show us some of the relevant parts of Map.

Comment: I can't see whats inside it- its a stanford library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling you, that the abstract class Map::Comparator needs a virtual destructor. If you delete an object through a pointer to base class, you invoke undefined behavior, if that base class contains no virtual destructor.

BTW: I would omit the empty constructor and destructor for your class. I would get nervous if I read your class declaration, seeing a destructor, but no copy constructor and no assignment operator.

Comment: I can't see what's in the map cpp, its part of the stanford libraries, the header says: #include "private/mapimpl.cpp"

Comment: So I can have the cpp file and the header file, without the constructor and destructor... and presumably without the Encoding:: scope before each function...?

Comment: @RobbieCooper Yes, the constructor and destructor you wrote are exactly the implementations, that the compiler generates for you. In this case, you better omit them. One reason I prefer that you omit them, is that you've picked 2 of 4 functions that the compiler generates for you.

Comment: @RobbieCooper If the library is this: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/materials/cppdoc/map-h.html the missing virtual destructor is a bug and should be reported to the author. To fix it, simple add the following line to the declaration of Comparator: ´virtual ~Comparator() {}´

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks. I think I'm just going to use two arrays instead of the map, and write key + value to the same index on each one.

Comment: WOW! Thats awesome Torsten, thankyou!!! I'll write them an email- although I'm not actually at Stanford, I'm in the UK doing the course online...

Comment: @RobbieCooper just have a look into the C++ standard library. There is already a map class in the header <map> named std::map.